# Tomcat access log - body of a request shows in the next request

Tags: logging, tomcat, http

I have a weird behavior in my tomcat (7).

An external app sends a bunch of DELETE requests with a body to my TomCat WebApp.
The body is being neglected in the webapp (I dont know why the app sends it, the paramters the webapp needs are in the url).
When the app sends about 20 request - a few are being ignored by the webApp.

Looking at the Tomcat access logs I see the following strange thing.
Right after the delete (line 2) The body of the delete is concatenated to the next request as a prefix(line 3).

Then I get 505.

Below - line 3 contains a prefix before POST /rest/dogs/tag HTTP/1.1" 405 1013.

```
172.31.13.77 - - [03/Mar/2016:14:08:43 +0000] "GET /rest/dogs/123 HTTP/1.1" 200 4095
172.31.13.77 - - [03/Mar/2016:14:09:07 +0000] "DELETE /rest/dogs/123 HTTP/1.1" 200 63
172.31.13.77 - - [03/Mar/2016:14:09:07 +0000] "{..HERE IS THE BODY(PayLoad) OF PREVIOUS DELETE.....}POST /rest/dogs/tag HTTP/1.1" 405 1013
```

Comment: Did you check the body for control characters?

Comment: Please make sure to add the answers that you get from crossposting on the tomcat mailing list here as well. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: I usually do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313027/rabbitmq-how-do-i-delete-all-messages-from-a-single-queue/5313988#5313988